# Let me know in the following pseudo code ,which execute in driver and which execute in executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In the following pseudo code ,which execute in driver and which execute in executor ?? why ??

Dataset1 = Dataset 0   (deriving Dataset1 from Dataset 0) 
  Dataset 2  = Dataset 1 , Dataset 0 
  Action on dataset 2 
  Dataset 3  =  Dataset1 , Dataset 2

As well let me know below pseudo code

dataframe = spark.sql("select * from emp")
dataframe=dataframe.withColumn("fullname",dataframe.empfirstname+dataframe.emplastname)
dataframe.count()
dataframe.show()

Comment: All the transformations will run in worker node ie executor  and all the action will run in driver node. .count and .show will run on driver node. Rest will on worker node.

Comment: In above case i am deriving Datasets from existing datasets . I.e does it happens in Driver or Executor ??

Answer (score 0):

Both.  On the driver spark will take your code and compile an execution graph and create a series of rdd based transforms that will mostly run on the executors.  Spark is smart enough to recognize that some dataframes are small enough to be read directly from the driver. The cut over point is usually 10MB.  Once most of the execution happens on the works the .show(..) function will load the output data from the executors to display.  Use .explain() to get spark to print the query plan.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Andrew, Can i get any reference doc or link to understand more.